# Rendering textures causing memory leak

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, libgdx

Inside my game I have this code. It renders a texture that serve as a button:

```
private void drawStart(){

    startTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("start.png"));
    startTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    stageStart = new Stage();
    stageStart.clear();
    buttonStart = new Image(startTexture);
    buttonStart.setX(10);
    buttonStart.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2.75f);
    buttonStart.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4);
    buttonStart.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4);




    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageStart);

    buttonStart.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
           currentState = GameState.RESET;
           startTexture.dispose();
           stageStart.dispose();


            return true;
        }
    });
    stageStart.addActor(buttonStart);
    stageStart.draw();
    startTexture.dispose();
```

}

However, whenever I put drawStart(); into my render method, the Java Heap and Native Heap slowly increases by 1 every 10 seconds. So, if the user leaves the game on the menu for about 5 minutes the game will crash on their phone. I've tested it and it only occurs when the texture is rendered.

I would appreciate any help on fixing this. I have tried an if statement that states if rendered = 0, render the texture then set rendered 1 but that didn't work.

Comment: Why would you put `drawStart()` into your render method? That's  basically creating a new Texture, new Stage (without properly disposing it), new Image and a new ClickListener around 60 times per second?

Comment: Sorry for my bad code, I've only learnt java 3 months ago. How would I go about only rendering it once?

Comment: Libgdx isn't the best start for learning java. If you mean that you think that you know (and understand) enough of java to take the step into libgdx, then i'd suggest having a look at one of [the tutorials](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/External-tutorials), so that you're sure to understand the [lifecycle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle). However, like said, at least basic knowledge about java, oop (and especially gc) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you. You only need draw in your render. So now you can put drawStart() in your render method which will only draw the stage, while leaving screen dont forget to call dispose.

```
    private void drawStart(){
        stageStart.draw();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        startTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("start.png"));
        startTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        stageStart = new Stage();
        stageStart.clear();
        buttonStart = new Image(startTexture);
        buttonStart.setX(10);
        buttonStart.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2.75f);
        buttonStart.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4);
        buttonStart.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageStart);

        buttonStart.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
               currentState = GameState.RESET;
               startTexture.dispose();
               stageStart.dispose();


                return true;
            }
        });
        stageStart.addActor(buttonStart);
    }

    public void dispose() {
         startTexture.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, only using up 1MB in Java Heap and Native Heap now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that in `drawStart()` you are creating new `Texture`s and a new `Stage`.
If you call this every render loop, you create new `Texture`s and a `new Stage` about 60 times/second.
This ofc causes a memory leak. 
You should load/create `Texture`s and the `Stage` only once, in the constructor or in the `create()` or `show()` method.
Also think about disposing them when needed. [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) is a list of the things you need to dispose manually.
In the render loop you should then only update and draw the things.

But as you only have 3 month of experience i suggest you to learn the basics first. Don't rush into game programming, it will kill your motivation.
First learn the basics, then start with some ASCII-Games (commandline) and then you can start with libgdx.

If you are ready for libgdx, read the [Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) (at least the parts you need) as well as some [tutorials](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/External-tutorials) (maybe they don't use the latest version of libgdx, but the concept should be more or less the same and it should help you understanding it.)